# What does "developing its results" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In The Markenmore Mystery (1922) by J. S. Fletcher, a financier was talking about another murdered financier who would have been his partner in a business deal of purchasing a secret of a formula for manufacturing a valuable dye:

> Now, very recently, Markenmore wrote to me that he had a business deal on in which I should find it profitable to join, with the idea of developing its results in the States.

**Does it mean "growing its returns"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you develop a business, you make it grow [bigger and more successful (3)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/develop), which, eventually, will bring you more profit.